# Cannot login to SQL Server 2008 R2 with Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When i try to connect to SQL Server (2008 R2) using Windows authentication:

[image]

i cannot:

[image]

Checking the Windows **Application** event log, i find the error:

> Login failed for user 'AVATOPIA\ian'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: ]

- **Log Name:** Application
- **Source:** MSSQLSERVER
- **Event ID:** 18456
- **Level:** Information
- **User:** AVATOPIA\ian
- **OpCode:**
- **Task Category:** Logon

i can login to the computer itself using Windows authentication. i can log into SQL Server using the *local* Windows Administrator account.

We can connect to 8 other SQL Servers on the domain using Windows Authentication. Just this one, whitch is the only one that is **2008 R2** is failing. So i assume it's a bug with **2008 R2*.

**Note:** i cannot logon locally, or remotely, using Windows authentication. i can login locally and remotely using SQL Server Authentication.

---

### Update

**Note:** It's not limited to SQL Server Management Studio, standalone applications that connect using Windows authentication:

[image]

fail:

[image]

**Note:** It's not a client problem, as we can connect fine to **other** (non-SQL Server 2008 R2 machines):

[image]

i'm sure there's a technote or knowledge base article describing why SQL Server 2008 R2 is [broken](https://serverfault.com/questions/204008/connecting-to-sql-server-2008-through-an-adsl-router) [by](https://serverfault.com/questions/155175/does-iis7-not-support-asp-net-by-default) [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512244/cant-step-into-stored-procedure-on-remote-sql-server-2008), but i can't find it.

### Update 2

[Matt](https://serverfault.com/a/346533/4822) figure out the change that Microsoft made so that SQL Server 2008 R2 is [broken by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512244/cant-step-into-stored-procedure-on-remote-sql-server-2008):

> Administrators are no longer administrators

[image]

All that remains is to figure out how to make Administrators administrators.

One of these days i'm going to start a list of changes around Microsoft's "broken by default" initiative.

### Steps to reproduce the problem

How do i add a group to the **sysadmin** fixed server role? Here's the steps i try, that don't work:

1. Click **Add**:

   [image]
2. Click **Object Types**:

   [image]
3. Ensure that you have no ability to add groups:

   [image]

   and click **OK**.
4. Under **Enter the object names to select**, enter `Administrators`:

   [image]
5. Click **Check Names**, and ensure that you are not allowed to add groups:

   [image]

   and click **Cancel**.
6. Click **Browse...**, and ensure that you have no ability to add groups:

   [image]

You should now still not have added any group to the **sysadmin** role.

### Additional information

- SQL Server Management Studio is being run as an administrator:

  [image]
- SQL Server is set to use Windows Authentication:

  [image]
- tried while logged into SQL with both `sa` and the only other sysadmin domain account (screenshot can be supplied for those who don't believe)

Comment: I have also found SQL confusing in this regard. You can only add "logins" to a role. You will first need to create a "login" for your group by going to Security -> Logins, right clicking and choosing 'New Login'. When you click 'Search', you can select the 'Groups' in Object Types, then click over to the 'Server Roles' tab and check the 'sysadmin' role. Click OK and you should be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@squillman provided the solution](https://serverfault.com/a/346721/4822) in a separate question.

This is a known issue with SQL Server 2008, and future products. The fix is to run:

```
CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS
go
sp_addsrvrolemember
      @LogiName='BUILTIN\Administrators',
      @RoleName='sysadmin'
```

The important point being that cannot add a "group" to a server role directly. You have to add a "login" ***for*** that "group". Then you can add that "login":

e.g. **Fails**:

> `BUILTIN\Administrators` -> **sysadmin**

**Works**:

> `BUILTIN\Administrators` -> BUILTIN\Administrators -> **sysadmin**

Answer (score 4):

As Matt has stated the Windows login you are using has not been setup and you will need to add it with a login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

You do not need to be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role to simply connect to your SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

BTW, during the R2 install, one is able to specify login(s) that need to be added to the sysadmin fixed server role.

**UPDATE - How to enable the adding of groups in SQL Server security**
[image: How to add a Windows group in SQL Server]

After including groups, you can find them (if they exist) using the Check Names in the Select User or Group pop-up.

Comment: How do i add "everyone"? Trying to add `BUILTIN\Administrators`, `Administrators`, `Everyone` all fail with ***An object name "[Everyone]" cannot be found.***

Comment: @Ian Boyd, you will need to check the 'Groups' checkbox under 'Object Types...' on the Select User or Group popup window when adding a new login. By default, 'Groups' is not checked.

Comment: @JK-SRS i updated the question with detailed screenshots showing there are no checkboxes. If you can add some screenshots showing there **is** checkboxes, we can compare screenshots and see who's missing what.

Answer (score 1):

- Is the SQL server on a different domain to your PC
- Have you added your user as a sysadmin role?

(To do this login to the server as sa - go to security - add the domain user if it doesn't exist - open the properties on the user - goto server roles and select sysadmin)

Should be able to login then.

Comment: i see what you mean, `BUILTIN\Administrators` is no longer added to the **sysadmin** server role. How does one add `Administrators` to the **sysadmin** role?

Comment: Updated question with detailed screenshots showing the inability of adding users or groups to any fixed server role (and the inability to create any new roles)

Comment: Add domain administrators (if you're a domain admin) to the list of users for the object sysadmin

Comment: See screenshots of no ability to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your instance is called SQLEXPRESS, then you need to use .\SQLEXPRESS or (local)\SQLEXPRESS or  yourMachineName\SQLEXPRESS as your server name - if you have a named instance, you need to specify that name of the instance in your server name.

Comment: -1 The OP states that he can connect to the instance using a SQL login and the builtin administrator account.  This means that making connections is not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Run this query after logging in sa mode..

CREATE LOGIN [your current pc name\UserName] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
    GO

It worked for me in all cases..